# Anyone Know of a Free Site Search?

Tags: search

I'm looking for a free site search engine.  One that requires very little up-keep and doesn't spam my users with ads.  Ideally it would be easy to implement, easy to maintain, and not require any massive installation procedure.

Also, I am trying to avoid google custom search.

Please let me know of any products that you think would satisfy those requirements!

Thanks

Comment: Google Custom Search seems to satisfy all of your requirements perfectly, up until that one where you say you don't want to use it. Any particular reason why not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use perlfect Search from sourceforge.net

Perlfect Search is a free, sophisticated, powerful, versatile, customizable and effective site indexing/searching suite available under an open source license (GPL).

It comes as a pair of distinct scripts. The indexer, that automatically scans and indexes a web site, and the search engine, a cgi script that serves search queries for keywords over the index, and displays results pages in html, in a standard format including title, description and relevance ranking for each matching document. Advanced features include stopwords, a potent exclude mechanism and a handy automatic installation and configuration utility.

Download: You can download Perlfect Search in either tar.gz (Linux/Unix) or zip (Windows) format:

[* Download Perlfect Search 3.37 from sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=156963)

Answer (score 1):

### [Yahoo! Search BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/)

> BOSS (Build your Own Search Service) is Yahoo!'s open search web services platform. The goal of BOSS is simple: to foster innovation in the search industry. Developers, start-ups, and large Internet companies can use BOSS to build and launch web-scale search products that utilize the entire Yahoo! Search index. BOSS gives you access to Yahoo!'s investments in crawling and indexing, ranking and relevancy algorithms, and powerful infrastructure. By combining your unique assets and ideas with our search technology assets, BOSS is a platform for the next generation of search innovation, serving hundreds of millions of users across the Web.

Answer (score 1):

"Easy to implement and maintain" are a bit relative, so I'm not sure where your threshold lies. But if you rule out things such as Google CSE (and similar offerings from other search engines), then you need to consider installing some search software on your servers and doing the indexing yourself.

One can get started with [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) very quickly if you are prepared to write some scripts to bulk index your site content into it. If you want a tool to crawl your site for you and index it, then [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is a solid choice. I've installed it a used it to crawl and search a website in less than one day. Extra bonus for combining Solr with Nutch (read up [here](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunningNutchAndSolr) and [here](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/03/09/nutch-solr/)). I hear their latest integration is more seamless than ever now that Solr has been rolled into Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind crawling your own pages, you could implement your own with Lucene. Lucene is a great open-source full-text search engine, and the advantage to using it is you can do things your way. It's quite easy to use after spending 15 minutes reading some tutorials.

It's available for [Java](http://lucene.apache.org/) and [.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) (and others).